# POST using HttpClient fro content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded using grant_type and scope

Tags: post, httpclient, httpresponse

I am trying to get the token from an endpoint using below code.

```
 var bodyContents = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
            { "userName", "loremipsum" },
            { "password", "xxxxxxx"},
            { "scope", "read_rulesengine write_rulesengine" }
        };

        string responseContents = string.Empty;

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test-sts-dev.test.com");
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/oauth/ls/connect/token");
        req.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(bodyContents);
        var postResponse = await client.SendAsync(req);
        postResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        if (!postResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new HttpRequestException("Access denied by token issuer. Check credentials in <encryptedSettings> of config file and try again.");

        responseContents = postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var responseObject = JObject.Parse(responseContents);

        return responseObject.Value<string>("access_token");
```

Now i think i am doing everything as correct but the in response iam getting **BadRequest**

Below is the response which i am getting :

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://test-sts-dev.test.com/oauth/ls/connect/token', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Content-Length: 125
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we'll i figured it out that i was missing the authorization setting in request :

```
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + auth); // auth will be string visible in postman after Basic
```

Placing this started giving me the result.